# Implement a decision tree in SharePoint

Tags: .net, sharepoint, moss, decision-tree

What is the best way to implement a decision tree in SharePoint? Is there a web part available? Does any of Sharepoint's Fab 40 templates contain a decision tree web part? i have searched but i couldnt find a useful answer anywhere.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity, a very rudimentary out of the box solution could be the Survey web part. It has some branching logic in it based on yes/no type answers.

Comment: yes u r right ... i have proposed the survey web part to the client already ... but i m looking for a better solution as well so i have an alternative ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [MindManager for SharePoint](http://www.mindjet.com/products/mindmanager-for-sharepoint/overview)?